# HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: caused by certificate

Tags: api, rest, automation, python-requests, robotframework

certificate verify failed:  SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool  HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:

Using Robot framework for API Testing getting an error HTTP Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: When  Create Session is set to False

```
Create Session  mysession  ${ADSS_API_URL}    verify=False
${body}=  Create Dictionary      username   aXXXXX      password    XXXXXX
${header}=  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json
${response}=    POST On Session  mysession  /login  data=${body1}  headers=${header}
log    ${response}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 POST_Create_a_new_project_Data_Driven
    [Arguments]     ${base_url}      ${token}       ${projects_name}    ${colorCode}    ${comment_count}    ${shared}   ${sync_id}  ${response_status}
       ${proxies}=      Create Dictionary       http=http://10.254.133.223:8800     https=http://10.254.133.232:8800
       Create Session    alias=todoist      url=${base_url}       verify=False      proxies=${proxies}
       &{headers}=       Create Dictionary      Authorization=${token}       Content-Type=application/json       X-Request-Id=$(uuidgen)     Cache-Control=no-cache
       &{reqest_body}=      Create Dictionary       name=${projects_name}
       ${respond}=   POST On Session   todoist    url=${base_url}       json=${reqest_body}       headers=${headers}    expected_status=${response_status}
```

Comment: I thank issue happen because proxy. You can try my code to by pass proxy